# Pandas read_html error - NoneType object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, wikipedia

I am trying to load a wikipedia table into a pandas dataframe, but I keep receiving an error notification ''NoneType' object has no attribute 'items''. I believe Python is importing the data as a list instead of a dataframe, but when I run df = data[0], i figured that was extracting a df.
I've tried a few ways, but going with the simple code for now:

```
url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M'
data = pd.read_html(url)
df = data[0]
df
```

when I check the type of df, pandas tells me its a dataframe (pandas.core.frame.dataframe)
I consistently receive the following error message:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmwXK.jpg)

Thanks in advance.. having a tough time with this

Comment: it just works for me.  python 3.7.6 pandas 1.1

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your `data` contains mixed types that pandas did not capture when loading the data from url. You may try adding `low_memory=False` when doing `pd.read_html()`